# Javascript wrap text with tags bbcode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bbcode

is there anyway to wrap textarea text with tags ?
Javascript/Jquery

> B = Bold I = Italic U = Underline S = Strike

**For example:**

```
-+-+-+-+-
 B I U S
-+-+-+-+-
<textarea>
 Some text here
</textarea>
```

When i highlight "here" and then click on bold its will be smth like this.

```
-+-+-+-+-
 B I U S
-+-+-+-+-
<textarea>
 Some text [b]here[/b]
</textarea>
```

Hope i will find solution
and this is it thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the solution

```
function wrapText(elementID, openTag, closeTag) {
    var textArea = $('#' + elementID);
    var len = textArea.val().length;
    var start = textArea[0].selectionStart;
    var end = textArea[0].selectionEnd;
    var selectedText = textArea.val().substring(start, end);
    var replacement = openTag + selectedText + closeTag;
    textArea.val(textArea.val().substring(0, start) + replacement + textArea.val().substring(end, len));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

useage

```
console.log(parseBB('[b]hello [/b][u]world[/u]'));
console.log(parseBB(document.getElementById('textareaID').value));
console.log(parseBB($('#textareaID').val()));
```

test case

```
$('#output-container').html(parseBB($('#textareaID').val()));
```

..

```
function parseBB(string){
var _string = string.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'),
parseExp = new RegExp(/^(.*)\[(b|u|i|s)\]([A-Za-z0-9 ._-]+)\[\/[a-z]+\](.*)$/g);

(function run(){
    if(parseExp.test(_string)){
        _string = _string.replace(parseExp , '$1<$2>$3</$2>$4');
        run();
    }
})();
return _string;
}
```